# Dynamic Arrays of Struct

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct, realloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ver{
    double x;
    double y;
};

struct ver *v=NULL;

int main(){

    v=(struct ver*)realloc(v,1*sizeof(struct ver));

    v[0].x=1.444;
    v[0].y=1.555;

    v[1].x=1.333;
    v[1].y=1.222;

    v[3].x=1.111;
    v[3].y=1.777;

    v[8].x=1.999;
    v[8].y=1.888;

    printf("x:%f y:%f \n", v[0].x, v[0].y);
    printf("x:%f y:%f \n", v[1].x, v[1].y);
    printf("x:%f y:%f \n", v[3].x, v[3].y);
    printf("x:%f y:%f \n", v[8].x, v[8].y);
}
```

The result is:

```
 x:1.444000 y:1.555000 
 x:1.333000 y:1.222000 
 x:1.111000 y:1.777000 
 x:1.999000 y:1.888000
```

Shouldn't i get segmentation fault? It ignores the realloc. 
I want to make an array of structs which i want to expand 1 array-cell each time.

Comment: Segfaults are a page-granularity thing, if you're using unallocated memory on an allocated page you're just destroying whatever happened to be there (which might be nothing)

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` and friends in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only get a segmentation fault if there is no memory behind the address you are accessing. This is meant in a physical sense, a segfault is first signaled by hardware, not by software. Now, physical memory mapping always happens in terms of complete pages. which are 4 kiB on most hardware. The size you requested from `realloc()` is just 16 bytes.

Of course, there must be memory behind the address that `realloc()` returns. Consequently, there must be at least 4080 addresses surrounding your struct that are just as valid in the eyes of the hardware as the 16 addresses belonging to the struct itself. That means that the hardware cannot signal your OS that something might be amiss, and your OS cannot send you a segmentation fault. You might get a segfault if you try to access `v[1000]`, but even that is not certain.

That does not mean that you are allowed to access these addresses, it just means that you cannot rely on a segfault when you access them. There might be other allocations that you can clobber, or worse, there might be information standing there which malloc uses to determine which memory regions are used and which not. If you access any address outside of the region requested from `realloc()`, your program has undefined behaviour and *anything* can happen.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `realloc` to allocate a single entry. Accessing anything but `v[0]` is *undefined behavior* which *may* cause a crash, or it may not.

Technically, defining `main` like you do (without any arguments, not even `void`) is also undefined behavior as well in C. You either have to declare it with `void` as argument, or `int` and `char**`.

Comment: I wonder how his code even compiles. Return type is int yet there is no return statement...

Comment: @user1075375 In the newer C standards, `main()` is special in that it will implicitly return zero if there is no explicit return. So this is perfectly legal C.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `realloc` with a `NULL` pointer is well defined behaviour. So v points to enough memory for exactly one struct ver.

The reason that `v[1]` is not generating a segmentation fault: Such errors do not have to happen alwyas - you can get lucky... Perhaps `realloc` also gives you a bit more memory as you only asked for 16 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `malloc` grabs a big chunk from the OS (so it can use it later) without doing a context switch.

That is expensive.

So you are just lucky